# Wood filler for rotted areas

Tags: wood, trim

I have a complex fascia consisting of a 1x4 over a 1x6 over a 2x8 in a stepped fashion. We have some rot issues in some locations. With one of the worst offenders, I had to replace a 16 foot area of fascia which was no easy task as the drip edge was nailed to the 1x4 through the osb roof sheathing and the corner bevel/miters were difficult to make perfect.

Elsewhere around the house, there are a few pieces rotted but none as bad, mostly either the 1x4 or the bottom of the 2x8 in max 2-4 foot sections. As I really don't want to replace all this wood I was thinking of doing a dutchman patch in these areas using my multitool to remove the rotted material.

However, I was wondering if there was some sort of putty I could use to fill rather large areas that are rotted after removing the rot. The material would have to be rather stiff so it could be formed rather deep (3/4 inch) and sticky so that it could adhere to the wood. I was thinking of kitty hair, however, other suggestions are welcome.

Spackle and wood filler wouldn't work.

Comment: in hindsight i agree, flagged to be moved

Comment: On DIY I suspect you're going to be steered towards replacing the sections or removing the rotted wood and patching rather than using a filler, although there are fillers that can do some of what you want scarfing in solid wood is far preferable because it will accommodate movement and weathering better. Polyester and epoxy fillers work best for patching larger voids when the wood is fairly rigid and can't move much in service, as on sills.

Answer (score 1):

**[Durham's Rock Hard Water Putty](https://www.lowes.com/pd/durham-s-64-fl-oz-light-yellow-patching-and-spackling-compound/3143343?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-pnt-_-google-_-lia-_-133-_-wallrepair-_-3143343-_-0&kpid&store_code=749&k_clickID=go_625682584_34615018630_111134780950_aud-299487635250:pla-260326515081_c_9013288&gclid=Cj0KCQjwjpjkBRDRARIsAKv-0O0FUBiu4lcohQU6O8q82Bpk6qBEihPzHZYjXoCrIXh0wvVIw9kJVf4aAj3cEALw_wcB)** is a great product. You can mix it as thick as you like using water. It sticks well, but can still be formed. Dries super hard relatively quick. Easy clean up and can be sanded and painted. The best part is that it doesn't shrink.

[image: Durham's Putty]

Comment: How does this product perform if it gets wet again? For example in an exterior application where it could be exposed to rain and snow.

Answer (score 0):

There are round wooden plugs available. Wolfcraft  for example sells some: http://www.wolfcraft.com/en/products/p/wooden_plugs/wooden_plugs/s/p/index.html

Drill out the rotten part, apply some wood filler at the edges.

Answer (score 0):

It can be treated with wood hardener, avaible at most big box hardware ans paint stores. Fill the voids auto body filler (Bondo) to fill voids.